# CloudSqlExecuteQueryOperator does not return results to xcom

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I have an airflow pipeline that does an UPSERT to a postgresql database on GCP cloud sql. Now, before I was using the PostgresOperator on a local database and everything was working fine, but needed to move my DAG execution to Cloud Composer with cloud sql. I followed a rather complicated set of steps to allow connectivity to my database through a pod in the cloud composer's kubernetes cluster. I can confirm that is working! I have some operators that successfully create tables in the database. although, My issue arises when I try to get values back from the CloudSqlExecuteQueryOperator.

I have the following templated SQL command...

```
WITH input_rows(plate_name, plate_type, number_wells) AS (
  VALUES
    {% for row in ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_message_rows', key='return_value') %}
    ('{{ row['plate'] }}', 'culture', 384) {{ ",\n" if not loop.last else "" }}
    {% endfor %}
    )
, ins AS (
  INSERT INTO plate (plate_name, plate_type, number_wells)
  SELECT * FROM input_rows
  ON CONFLICT (plate_name) DO NOTHING
  RETURNING plate_id, plate_name, plate_type, number_wells
  )
SELECT 'i' AS source
    , plate_id, plate_name, plate_type, number_wells
FROM ins
UNION ALL
SELECT 's' AS source
    , c.plate_id, input_rows.plate_name, input_rows.plate_type, input_rows.number_wells
FROM input_rows
JOIN plate c USING (plate_name);
```

the operator in question then is executed like this...

```
write_plates = CloudSQLExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id="write_plates",
        sql=sql_plate_template,
        gcp_cloudsql_conn_id=connection_name, # environment variable AIRFLOW_CONN_<conn_id>
    )

# this operator fails because it is getting a NoneType
formatted_results = some_python_operator_with_decoration(write_plates.output)

write_plates >> formatted_results
```

I see the inserted rows in my table, and when I manually run this query I get return values how I expected. Does the CloudSqlExecuteQueryOperator simply not have the ability to return to XCOM? Should I set autocommit to true? is there a work around I have to do? I was hoping to get a return similar to the PostgresOperator where you can iterate through the rows and columns like so...

```
@task
def some_python_operator_with_decoration(postgres_results)
    results = []
    for row in postgres_results:
        results.append({'source': row[0], "id": row[1], "name": row[2]})
    return results
```

Comment: I just dug into the source code and the person who wrote the operator was nice enough to explain it in the comments: "this operator does not return any data from the database". I'll see if I can't connect to the cloud SQL with a PostgresOperator.

Comment: This now spawns a new question that maybe I need to pose. I have a workload running cloud_sql_proxy binary in the kubernetes cluster from following this blog: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/connecting-gcp-composer-to-cloud-sql-via-proxy-305743a388a. I tried to expose it with a static cluster ip and through ports on all the pods, but no matter what I try I can't get a successful connection.

Comment: okay, I can port forward the the proxy to my workstation. for example, port 5432 of the pod where the proxy is listening is forwarded to 8080 on my laptop. It works fine with the psql client that way. I think it must be the ports that are open in the airflow containers themselves that is not allowing it to reach the proxy workload. If thats the case, it may be impossible to connect as I cannot edit that in compose. Perhaps I can start the proxy in the operator itself? it looks like CloudSqlExecuteQueryOperator does this in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CloudSqlExecuteQueryOperator does not return any queries](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/cloud_sql.html#cloudsqlexecutequeryoperator:%7E:text=Performs%20DDL%20or%20DML%20SQL%20queries%20in%20Google%20Cloud%20SQL%20instance.%20The%20DQL%20(retrieving%20data%20from%20Google%20Cloud%20SQL)%20is%20not%20supported.%20You%20might%20run%20the%20SELECT%20queries%2C%20but%20the%20results%20of%20those%20queries%20are%20discarded.), according to the documentation. you can work around this by deploying a pod by following the steps google has on connecting to [cloud sql from kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#run_the_in_a_sidecar_pattern). [This medium article](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/connecting-gcp-composer-to-cloud-sql-via-proxy-305743a388a) does a decent job walking you through it as well as this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/Just1B/26d85511a053ce906ea4a2b02fbb3531). Once you have the service running in your composer environment, you can treat it as a regular Postgres connection in airflow. Although I will add one thing. when you deploy the container running cloud-sql-proxy, **make sure to explicitly tell cloud-sql-proxy to host it on "0.0.0.0"**. I had everything working but could not figure out why nothing could connect. It defaults to hosting it on "127.0.0.1". For some reason, my other services like airflow could connect only when I made this change.